# Angular prepend to top with ng-repeat off by one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add an object to the top of my list, rather than bottom, with `ng-repeat`. I thought the way to do this would be `unshift` or `splice` with index 0, but one pesky object remains at the top.

Datastructure:

```
$scope.categories = [
    {...}, {...}, {...}
]
```

Add object function:

```
$scope.addObj = function () {
    $scope.categories.unshift({
        category : ''
    });
};
```

How it appears in the HTML list:

- Object G
- Object K
- Object M
- Object P

**Click add obj**: How it appears in the HTML list **AFTER** prepending:

- Object G
- NEW OBJECT
- Object K
- Object M
- Object P

I `console.log`'ed my `$scope.categories` array and verified that the new object had been added at array index 0. What is going on here?

I initially tried `splice` with the same result:

```
$scope.addObj = function () {
    $scope.categories.splice(0, 0, {
        category : ''
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in categories | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchQuestions track by $index">
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : categoryForm.username.$invalid && !categoryForm.email.$pristine }">
            <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="New Category" class="form-control" ng-model="c.category" required>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: did you try after removing ' orderBy:sortType:sortReverse' in ng-repeat?

Comment: @MuthukannanKanniappan this fixes it but I need that so I can allow the user to sort alphabetically or reverse alphabetical

Comment: Unshift works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/yzs41q4g/

Answer (score 1):

Add the input form before ng-repeat

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : categoryForm.username.$invalid && !categoryForm.email.$pristine }">
            <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="New Category" class="form-control" ng-model="c.category" required>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="c in categories | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchQuestions track by $index">
   <td>
      {{c.category}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is a sample try modifying your code based on this.

categories.unshift will not guarantee to display the new item in first index because you have applied orderBy filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this.

```
$scope.addObj = function () {
 var c = $scope.categories.length + 1;
 var category = new String('category' + c)
$scope.categories.splice(0, 0, category);};
```